# Setup website alias in IIS to hide port number

Tags: iis, alias

Somebody once told me that it's possible to make some kind of alias for your website in IIS, so that users can just navigate to the (intranet) page, without being troubled with port numbers.

E.g.

`intranet.company.net:8081`

can be aliased to

`application.intranet.company.net`

I have no idea where to look to create these aliases in IIS, surprisingly enough searching for "alias iis" on Google / SO doesn't give me meaningful hits. Maybe it is simply not possible, but I really thought it was...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you trying to do this with?

Comment: about says: IIS7 version 7.5.7600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IIS7, you can configure a website `application.intranet.company.net` whose sole purpose is to redirect to the actual url, i.e. `intranet.company.net:8081`.

You can do this several ways, including web.config. The simplest way is to use the IIS management UI. [See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770409%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for instructions.

Comment: please add the answer